# Heroku and Emberjs Rails4 deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ember.js

the case is pretty simple to describe. this is the gem file

```
gem 'ember-rails'
gem 'ember-source', '1.0.0.rc6.2'
gem 'handlebars-source', '~> 1.0.12'
```

This is the Application.js file

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require foundation
//= require handlebars
//= require ember
//= require ember-data
//= require_self
//= require q
```

This is what I have in development.rb and production.rb

```
config.ember.variant = :development
config.ember.variant = :production
```

I tested everything in a production environment locally, everything worked just fine. when I push it to Heroku, I have the following error, I can't figure out what is the problem

```
 -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
   Running: rake assets:precompile
   rake aborted!
   couldn't find file 'handlebars'
   (in /tmp/build_2ddhwlktd9evz/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:17)
```

I forgot to mention I am using Rails4

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'ember-rails'
gem 'ember-source', '1.0.0.rc6'
gem 'handlebars-source', '1.0.0.rc4'
```

I am using Rails4 and this is currently working for me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I want to use the latest versions. I manged to make it work I pre-compiled locally then commit  the changes to the server, so I don't require Heroku  to compile assets. it worked fine.

Comment: I have also been trying to get the latest versions working but ember 1.0.0.rc6.1 is incompatible with the latest handlebars so you can't use handlebars-source 1.0.12 with it. If you find a solution please let me know.

Comment: As I wrote precompile the assets and git push them it works fine